# CakePHP Data Handling

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Good Day. I am a noob CakePHP programmer here.

In my Controller, I have this.

```
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $users = $this->User->find("all");
```

And when I did pr($users), the data seems to be complete.

But when I used $users in my View, and again I did pr($users) to check my data, only the display field and id of the User Model seems to be there.

Any ideas why is it such? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->recursive = 0;
$users = $this->User->find("all");
$this->set('users',$users);
```

If you get the Data in the Controller,and set to view then it displays the data same as what you are getting in the controller.